# Lendo String até encontrar determinado caractere

Tags: java

Posso receber dados como:

> 232321
>   ou
>   dwd

Mas as vezes, pode aparecer um "+" entre as Strings. Como faço para extrair somente o que vier ANTES desse caracter?

Se caso, eu tiver uma entrada assim: "432d+321"
ficaria: 432d.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
String str = "432d+321";
String res = str.split("\\+")[0];

// res = 432d.
```

Obs: para `meta caracteres`, deve-se usar as `'\\'`.

```
\ , ^ , $ , * , + , ?
```

Answer (score 5):

Faça assim:

```
String str = "432d+321";

int posicao = str.indexOf('+');
if (posicao >= 0) {
    str = str.substring(0, posicao);
}

System.out.println(str); // Imprime 432d
```